# Listing login information on the web safely?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I really don't think there is a way for this to be done safely but maybe there is a more outside the box way to approach the task.

I am working on a project management site.  Some of these projects would be Websites so the client wants to be able to display the ftp, database and hosting information.  This would require me to display username and passwords unencrypted on the web.  I obviously see the huge risk in this because if the site gets cracked it has information that could destroy other sites as well.

One way I can think to approach this is encrypting the passwords and then creating an application that they would keep locally on there machine to decrypt that password.  This is really the only "safe" way I can think of.

Comment: If they can all install a local application then just use one of those password applications and let them store the passwords.

Comment: I don't understand why you would have a need to display that kind of information.  What would the client be using it for?  Could you give out lower permission username/passwords or maybe one-time username/passwords?  I guess I'm not quite sure why you are doing this.

Comment: Well it's a project management tool.  So the purpose is to have a system that keeps track of all the current projects going on and all of the information that goes with them.

Comment: Why can't you simply use SSL?

Comment: Well SSL would keep the submission of the data safe but if someone managed to break into the system or get someones login they would have access to that information still.

Comment: Don't **ever** display passwords, use a password reset mechanism instead if a user `forgets` his password sent an email with a system generated password. No serious system ever displays passwords, nor does it need to.

Comment: Well the problem is that it is not their password.  It's a system that contains login information for potentially hundreds of sites.  The idea is for a system that makes it easy to keep track of all of this information in an area that multiple people can access.

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely need some sort of encryption (SSL is a good suggestion) to keep the passwords safe, but in terms of "viewing" them on the web you could do something like:

Have the user enter a 'site password'. You could also use a captcha to prevent bots from getting at your passwords. This will allow them to view their own password for a short period of time, say 10 seconds. Their password would be displayed in an input box, or some sort of box, that would be readonly. They should not be able to copy/paste passwords.

Having username and password information up on the screen is definitely a security risk, but this all depends on how security sensitive your information is going to be.

Another solution could be that if they need to view their password, they are required to change it the next time they log in. This will allow them to view their current password, but will negate the security risk of having that password stolen since they would be resetting it almost immediately.

All of this depends on how sensitive the information is of course.

Comment: Well the problem with that is they can't change the password after viewing it.  The login/pw is most likely set up by someone else and we would not have access to change it.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could use a javascript library to encrypt/decrypt datas on the client side, asking the user to enter a passphrase to decrypt datas locally when viewing them, and encrypt them before submission of a form. This way only crypted datas will transit over the network and wihtout the passphrase you only access crypted datas.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and safest way to do this would be to use SSL.

If you can't go that route than you'll need to come up with your own way of encrypting the information during transit. This is difficult. You'd need something like a Diffie-Hellman key exchange (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), a large number of primes for the client-side to choose from, and then javascript to encrypt and decrypt the information using the exchanged key. You could improve on this by having pre-cached the javascript, downloading it from a third party, and (preferably) doing a checksum to ensure that you JS hasn't been modified.

However, since the encryption code and primes are sent plain-text through the internet, they could be modified en route allowing an attacker to manipulate where POSTs will be sent and how information will be encrypted.

In short, if you're not using SSL, you have not way to guarantee that information is transferred securely.

One thing you might do is tap into PGP. If the user uploads their public key, you'd be able to return messages to them safely. This is because the PGP software is independent of the browser/internet.

Comment: Noone should entertain the idea of not using SSL for transit of sensitive information, ever.

Comment: @lunched-dan, obviously safely transferring information through an insecure medium requires encryption of some sort. SSL is a nice, well-packaged solution, but we both know there are many other encryption schemes in the world. Using these through HTTP is a perfectly plausible, secure, albeit inconvenient thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

- Start with SSL for the secure transit.
- Encrypt the information before storing it.
- Read some articles on how hackers get into these sites, plug the holes before you learn a difficult lesson.
- **NEVER** display a password, you don't need to. Use a login link, where you can include tokens and checks that ensure the user clicking on it has the appropriate permission level.

**Example:** Employee gets fired. He is upset captures the screen with all of the passwords on display. Not a great situation for your company or the former client.

Using my method, the user could capture the screen, copy the links, it would have no effect, as his token would be revoked and the link wouldn't work. Your client site is safer this way.